# Dropdown List ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Can someone help please? I got the code below that displays a drop down list of numbers 1-32. This works fine. I want to do the similar thing but instead have a dropdown list of just to show YES & NO.

Frontend code

```
<td>{DoAmendPallets(reader["Amend_Pallets"].ToString(), reader["Record_Status"].ToString(), loopCount)}</td>
```

`DoAmendPallets` method:

```
public string DoAmendPallets(string pallets, string status, int loopCount)
{
    var palletsArr = new string[33];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        palletsArr[i] = i.ToString();
    }

    palletsArr[32] = "32";

    return Builders.DoDropdown(palletsArr, "amendPallets", pallets.ToString(), loopCount);
}
```

Comment: What is `Builders`. Some kind of library or plugin that generates html snippets?

Comment: But you can do this: `var yesnoArr = new string[2]; yesnoArr[0] = "Yes"; yesnoArr[1] = "No"; return Builders.DoDropdown(yesnoArr,`